# How to get screen resolution of your android device..?

Tags: android, cordova, screen-resolution

**Can i get resolution of android phone..?**
if yes then how..?
it will really helpful for me..
Thank you..

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you want the display dimensions in pixels you can use getSize:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

This method was introduced in Android API 13, so if you want to get display metrics for previous APIs use:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int wwidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

If you're not in an Activity, you can get the default Display via `WINDOW_SERVICE`. Also be sure to set your minSdkVersion to at least 4 in AndroidManifest.xml to enable calls to display.getWidth().

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
```

**Edit: PhoneGap**

Use the following to figure out the display size in pixels

```
 function getDeviceDimention() {
        console.log("Device Dimention using PhoneGap");
        console.log("Width = " + window.innerWidth);
        console.log("Height = " + window.innerHeight);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. but I am using phonegap.. Is it possible to do it using javascript..?

Comment: Got it..
Thank you..
i m going to try it..

Comment: As i am new to stackoverflow,i didn't know about this.. so thnx again for providing information..

Comment: okies..
but how can i do this..?
By clicking on that star..?

Comment: its working but doesnt include soft key navigation area. how to include this?

Answer (score 10):

For Cordova / Phonegap, I've found that using

```
var width = screen.width
var height = screen.height
```

is more reliable than using

```
var width = window.innerHeight
var height = window.innerWidth
```

in order to obtain the resolution of the current display. The latter is unfortunately inaccurate if your mark-up either overflows or does not take up all of the space available on the screen.

Comment: I agree. Just be careful on some devices the height and width don't rotate with the display.

Answer (score 4):

For phonegap you can use this

You can use **device-width** and **device-height**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=no" />
```

You can even get device height and width using jquery & jquery mobile like this

```
var width = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height();
```

**NOTE:-** Do this when device is ready.

Comment: Its working..
Thnx bro..

Comment: Always mention in your heading  how you want to do it. So right people can help you... Chalo nice its Working for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can call

```
Display display = getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point outSize = new Point();
display.getRealSize(outSize);
```

outSize.x is the width and outSize.y is the height. Hope it help.

Comment: This requires API 17.

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth(); 
int height = display.getHeight();
```

look at this answer [Android: How to get screen dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1016941/964741)

Answer (score 1):

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int width = dm.widthPixels;
int height = dm.heightPixels;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much..
but I am using phonegap..
Is it possible to do it using javascript..?

Comment: Oh I realy don't mind. I didn't use it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

good luck
행운을 빈다.

Answer (score 0):

u can get screen resolution like this

```
  Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth(); 
    int height=display.getHeight();
```